# Difference in the meaning between "walk out on me" and "between "walk out me"?

Tags: prepositions

What is the exact difference in the meaning between "He walked out on me" and "He walked out me"?

What is the exact difference in the meaning between "He walked out on the door" and "He walked out the door"?

Comment: Do you mean *work*, which you have in your title, or *walk* which you have in the body of your question? Please edit to make these consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are some errors regarding tense in your examples.

> He walk**ed** out on me.

It sounds like this definition

> [walk out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/walk-out)
>   to suddenly leave your husband, wife, or partner and end your relationship with them:
>   *He walked out on his wife and two kids.*

Now,

> He walked out me

doesn't mean anything.

However, if you meant

> He walked me out

then it means

> [walk someone out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/walk+out)
>   to accompany someone out, walking.
>   *I'll walk you out. The exit is hard to find. Please let me walk you out so you don't get lost.*

> He walk**ed** out on the door

doesn't mean anything.

> He walk**ed** out the door.

*Walked* is the past tense of *walk*, and *out* is the usual preposition.
Or "walk out" means to leave, in this case, without the implication of "disapproval". I'm actually not sure. In either case, the meaning is that he used the door to exit the place.

Comment: I have thought it means that relationship between "He walked out on me" and "He walked out on the door" is a relationship between "He walked out me" and "He walked out the door". This is the part where I'm confused.

Comment: No unfortunately. Some of those have idiomatic meanings in addition to their literal meanings.

Comment: what is the meaning of "on"  in the sentence, "he walked out on me" ? Should i think that "on" mean "connection(relationship)" ?

Comment: @user175012 it expresses that the subject did something abruptly, rudely, or in some other hurtful way. Another quite common example of this usage is "they hung up on me!" meaning someone hung up the telephone  without properly ending the conversation.

Comment: You could also "walk out on" an employer, or on your friends. It can mean abandoning any relationship.

Comment: To be complete -- or to be nitpicky, depending on how you want to look at it -- you can "walk out on" an object in the literal physical sense: you walked out of one place, and stepped onto this object. Like, "I walked out on the balcony" or "I walked out on the red carpet." I suppose you could "walk out on a door" if the door was lying on the ground outside the entrance. Like, "The door was blown off its hinges by the explosion. Then I walked out on the door." Pretty unlikely, to say the least.

Comment: @Jay Yes, complete and nitpicky, agreed. I just offered that one definition for _walk out_ because that's what it sounded like. That's what came to (my) mind. It's possible, but hard to imagine a boss saying it. Also, I've been scolded for taking things literally before, so I didn't want to go there. But I do agree, you could literally "walk out on a door".

Comment: What probably said - plus 'He walked out the door' would be 'He walked out _of_ the door' in BrEng